# Options for Tikzpicture with newcommand

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I'd like to define options via newcommand, so i can use them for tikzpicture-environments.
I tried this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\test}{[every path/.style={->,red,thick}]}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}\test
\draw (0,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But the line is still black. Where is the mistake in my approach? i thought, newcommand simply expands its content when it is written. I assume that the square brackets are perhaps the problem...

Comment: Try `\newcommand{\test}{
\tikzset{every path/.style={->,red,thick}}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! While technically correct, the method given in [@ferahfeza's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526000/options-for-tikzpicture-with-newcommand/526024#comment1330441_526000) is probably not the one I would use here. Staying in the spirit of `pgfkeys`, I would define a `/tikz/test` style. This is often easier to reuse within Ti*k*Z pictures. Note that both methods allow one to take advantage of TeX's grouping rules, as shown below in the case of “my” method:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  test/.style={
    every path/.style={->, red, thick},
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[test] % '/tikz/test' style manually set for this picture
  \draw (0,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip
{%
  \tikzset{test}% Applies to the current TeX group, until (possibly) overridden
  %
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (1,1)--(0,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \qquad
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,1)--(1,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}% TeX group terminated; the '/tikz/test' style is not in effect anymore.

\bigskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0)--(1,1) (1,0)--(0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of NOT using \pgfkeys, one can use

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\test}{[every path/.style={->,red,thick}]}
\newcommand{\tikzstart}{\begin{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\expandafter\tikzstart\test
\draw (0,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```